# Is this an emphatic setence?

Tags: relative-clauses, negative-concord

> He [truck driver] held the screen door a little open. "Week–ten days,"
>   he said. "Got to make a run to Tulsa, an' I never get back soon as I
>   think." She [waitress] said crossly, "Don't let the flies in. Either
>   go out or come in." "So long," he said, and pushed his way out. The
>   screen door banged behind him. He stood in the sun, peeling the
>   wrapper from a piece of gum. He was a heavy man, broad in the
>   shoulders, thick in the stomach. His face was red and his blue eyes
>   long and slitted from having squinted always at sharp light. He wore
>   army trousers and high laced boots. Holding the stick of gum in front
>   of his lips he called through the screen, "Well, **don't do nothing
>   you don't want me to hear about**." The waitress was turned toward a
>   mirror on the back wall. She grunted a reply. The truck driver gnawed
>   down the stick of gum slowly, opening his jaws and lips wide with each
>   bite. He shaped the gum in his mouth, rolled it under his tongue while
>   he walked to the big red truck.
>  (John Steinbeck, The Grapes of
>   Wrath)

I can’t understand what the highlighted part means. Is ‘nothing’ an emphatic word instead of ‘anything,’ and is the sentence after nothing, the complementing clause (or modifier) for nothing?

Comment: It is similar to "I can't get no satisfaction." heard in a famous song, or "We don't need no education." heard in another one. Double negations are generally not emphatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the double negative "Don't do nothing" is not particularly emphatic; it's simply the dialect way of saying *Don't do anything*.

"You don't want me to hear about" is a relative clause with a Ø-relativizer, equivalent to *which you don't want me to hear about*.

So:

> Don't do anything which you don't want me to hear about.

It's not meant literally, it's just a jocular farewell cast in the form of a mock warning, intended to convey a friendly familiarity; but it fails to put the waitress in a good humor.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not more emphatic.

The speaker's English is fairly low-register. He's not well educated, but he speaks a common & widespread brand of English. The double negative of "don't do nothing" tells the reader only about the guy's level of formal education or about how well he's adapted (*When in Rome, do as the Romans do*) to the linguistic practices of the people he speaks with day in and day out -- probably the former.